How can I create a stacked barchart with this data using ggplot2?
This is the data I'm working with:



Station
Salinity
CentricD
PennateD
Dinoflag
MarineFlag
Cilliates




A3
18.3
181000
26500
1000
15500
2250


A6
27.4
584666.6667
4666.666667
11666.66667
0
61333.33333


A8
25.7
625071.4286
2000
74000
294.1176471
1907.563025


B
29.77785714
503693.8776
2000
6642.857143
7642.857143
5622.44898


C
31.283
266991.5966
5285.714286
10714.28571
71352.94118
12067.22689


D
32.21625
349375
6437.5
6142.857143
39651.78571
4339.285714


E
32.23
379200
466.6666667
3714.285714
12228.57143
4504.761905


F
32.8
559000
0
333.3333333
0
11000


G
33.185
209276.7857
2125
5714.285714
27937.5
3062.5


H
33.67
98714.28571
1812.5
7125
6410.714286
7750


I
34.33294118
113302.521
1764.705882
40142.85714
5588.235294
9260.504202


J
34.537
68142.85714
1000
12842.85714
20228.57143
5271.428571



I want to make a stacked barchart, with 'Station' on the x-axis, and then each type of phytoplankton stacked on top of each other per station to create a comprehensive idea of both how many phytoplankton there are per station and what that composition is made up of.
I just don't know how to do that. Looking at the geom_bar() command, I need to specify a 'fill' variable, of which I don't have just one, I have 5 types of phytoplankton that I want to fill it with.
I'm sure that this is just a data formatting issue, but I can't find any examples of how to properly format it. Thanks in advance.

You would first have to pivot the data to be in long format, then you could make the graph using the pivoted values as the y-axis values and the pivoted variable names as the fill variable.  Here's an example.
Original Data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Station , ~Salinity    , ~CentricD    , ~PennateD    , ~Dinoflag    , ~MarineFlag  , ~Cilliates   ,
"A3"      , 18.3        , 181000      , 26500       , 1000        , 15500       , 2250        ,
"A6"      , 27.4        , 584666.6667 , 4666.666667 , 11666.66667 , 0           , 61333.33333 ,
"A8"      , 25.7        , 625071.4286 , 2000        , 74000       , 294.1176471 , 1907.563025 ,
"B"       , 29.77785714 , 503693.8776 , 2000        , 6642.857143 , 7642.857143 , 5622.44898  ,
"C"       , 31.283      , 266991.5966 , 5285.714286 , 10714.28571 , 71352.94118 , 12067.22689 ,
"D"       , 32.21625    , 349375      , 6437.5      , 6142.857143 , 39651.78571 , 4339.285714 ,
"E"       , 32.23       , 379200      , 466.6666667 , 3714.285714 , 12228.57143 , 4504.761905 ,
"F"       , 32.8        , 559000      , 0           , 333.3333333 , 0           , 11000       ,
"G"       , 33.185      , 209276.7857 , 2125        , 5714.285714 , 27937.5     , 3062.5      ,
"H"       , 33.67       , 98714.28571 , 1812.5      , 7125        , 6410.714286 , 7750        ,
"I"       , 34.33294118 , 113302.521  , 1764.705882 , 40142.85714 , 5588.235294 , 9260.504202 ,
"J"       , 34.537      , 68142.85714 , 1000        , 12842.85714 , 20228.57143 , 5271.428571 )

Here, I use pivot_longer() from tidyr.  This will plot the raw values by station and phytoplankton.  Note, that if you are providing the y value directly (and not calculating it from the data), you need to use stat="identity" in geom_bar().
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(CentricD:Cilliates, names_to = "phyto", values_to = "val") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Station, y=val, fill = phyto)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme_bw()


If you would rather percentagize the figures so each bar has the same height, you could make the percentage variable by Station first and then plot that variable instead.

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(CentricD:Cilliates, names_to = "phyto", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(Station) %>% 
  mutate(pct = val/sum(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Station, y=pct, fill = phyto)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-12-04 with reprex v2.1.0
